# Can't have label on mid-stream declaration in C?

Tags: c, standards, c99, goto

So this in C99:

```
label:
  int ret = function(of, stuff);
```

gives a compile-time error, whereas this:

```
label:
  ;
  int ret = function(of, stuff);
```

works just fine.

Is this a compiler bug? Or is this a bug in the definition of the C standard? Or if this is part of the C99 standard, perhaps someone would rise to the defense of the C standard to claim that this makes perfect sense?

Comment: "Perhaps someone would rise to the defense of the C standard to claim that this makes perfect sense" -- well, you've certainly come to the right place.

Comment: Why these close votes ... :-S - a fair question, which I still remember very well ... :-)

Comment: Apparently questions about a programming language are not about programming?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Labels, which are defined in [N1256](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) 6.8.1 Labeled statements, can only contain *statements*.

> ```
>  Syntax  
> 1      labeled-statement:  
>            identifier : statement  
>            case constant-expression : statement  
>            default : statement
> ```

`int ret = function(of, stuff);` is an *declaration*, which is defined in N1256 6.7 Declarations and isn't a statement.

Statements are defined below in N1256 6.8 Statements and blocks:

> ```
>  Syntax
> 1      statement:
>            labeled-statement
>            compound-statement
>            expression-statement
>            selection-statement
>            iteration-statement
>            jump-statement
> ```

`compound-statement` is so-called *blocks*, which is 0 or more declarations and statements surrounded by `{}`.

`expression-statement` is zero or one expression defined in N1256 6.5 Expressions, followed by a semicolon like `i++;`. The *expression* in the syntax is defined in N1256 6.5.17 Comma operator.

`selection-statement` is `if` and `switch` statement.

`iteration-statement` is `while`, `do-while` and `for` statement.

`jump-statement` is `goto`, `continue`, `break` and `return` statement.

As you see, declarations are not a statement, so you cannot put labels to declarations.

Comment: So you could have eg. `label: {int ret = function(of, stuff); }`.

Answer (score 4):

Arguably a bug in the spec -- when it was changed to allow statements and declarations to be mixed in a block (rather than requiring all declarations before statements), it should also have been changed to allow labels on a declaration, but it was not.  An artifact of how the language evolved over time.

Its not a major problem as you discovered, as you can work around it trivially by putting the label on an empty statement before the declaration.

Comment: Perhaps but note that the same niggle and workaround predates C99 for trailing cases (or labels) in a switch. I'd guess that requiring a succeeding statement resolves some ambiguity or otherwise makes life easier for the parser.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if the purpose of forbidding declarations that follow statements was actually to ensure that it was impossible to jump from a point following a declaration to a point before the declaration without leaving the scope of that declaration.  Requiring that all variables in a *function* precede any executable code (as some pre-C89 compilres did) simplifies code generation, but I don't think the C89 rules offer any real advantage except to ensure that code which transfers control to a point before a declaration must necessarily leave its scope.